# Words starting with '@' doesn't match if I place in word boundary \b

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am using Regex in c# console app.
I've words starting with '@' in my string and I am using Regex to match those but that doesn't seem to be working.
Here's my code

```
public static void regularExpression()
    {
        string[] sentences = 
        {
            "@TODAY is 18 Dec",
            "@TODAY_CAL is 18 Dex",
            "@YESTERDAY was 17 dec",
            "@YESTERDAY_CAL was 17 Dec"
        };

        string sPattern = @"\b@TODAY\b";

        foreach (string s in sentences)
        {
            System.Console.Write("{0,24}", s);

            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("  (match for '{0}' found)", sPattern);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

    }
```

@TODAY doesn't match. If I replace the sPattern with

```
string sPattern = @"@TODAY";
```

it works. But in that case it matches even @TODAY_CAL, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.
I want to exact word to match.

Any suggestions???

Comment: Are you try match `@"@TODAY\s"`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string sPattern = @"@TODAY\b";
```